# ggplot by group does not get expected outcomes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame `oz.sim.long`. It has three columns. Please see below. The `Times` column should be the x axis in ggplot, i.e. hours from `00:30-23:00`. The `Month` is the column of groups (`03:08`). The `Ozone` column is to plot.

```
> oz.sim.long
# A tibble: 144 x 3
   Times Month Ozone   
   <chr> <chr> <fct>   
 1 00:30 03    44.45481
 2 00:30 04    49.43994
 3 00:30 05    50.86507
 4 00:30 06    48.97589
 5 00:30 07    46.31845
 6 00:30 08    44.78662
 7 01:30 03    44.47265
 8 01:30 04    49.46492
 9 01:30 05    50.83062
10 01:30 06    48.79744
# … with 134 more rows
```

Here is my code to plot and I got unexpected outcome. Any ideas?

```
simul.plt <- ggplot(data = oz.sim.long, aes(x=Times, y=Ozone)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Month,color=Month)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(color=Month, linetype=Month), method = 'auto', se = F) + 
  labs(x='Times',y='Ozone (ppb)')
```

[image: My plot]

Comment: your values for ozone are a factor, not a numeric - convert them and your y axis will look right

Comment: @Greg Good point. I did not notice that. I converted ozone to be numeric, however there was no lines in the plot. Any ideas??

Comment: Times is a character vector you need to convert it to a datetime or a numeric

Comment: `aes(x = chron(times = Times), y = Ozone)` with the `chron` package will do what @GeorgeSavva mentioned